# Mongoose routes for updating fields provided

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been reading some CRUD / Mongoose guides, but haven't a good explainer for conditionally updating fields.

So for example, an action called updateItem is used in one place to update item.price but in another place it updates item.color. Does anyone know a good explanation or tutorial for Mongoose CRUD APIs that shows this?

I'm getting the blow code to work fine, but I have a feeling it could be cleaner :)

Thanks!!!

```
router.put('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
  Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
    req.body.owner ? { owner: req.body.owner } : { hours: req.body.hours }, { new: true })
    .then(task => {
      res.status(201).json(task)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Our error', err)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach you could take is to first retrieve the object, and then only update the value if it is passed into the put request. An example of that could be something like this:

```
router.put('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
  let price = req.body.price;
  let color = req.body.color;

  Task.findById(req.params.id, function (err, task) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    task.color = color || task.color;
    task.price = price || task.price;

    task.save(function(err, updatedTask) {
        if err return handleError(err);
        return res.send(updatedTask);
    });   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's another cleaner approach using [async-await functions](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/):**

```
// Import promisify from utils
const promisify = require('utils').promisify;

// Wrap findByIdAndUpdate into a promise
const updateOwnerPromise = promisify(Task.findByIdAndUpdate);

// Write an async handler now
updateOwnerPromiseAsync = async (req, res) => {

    const replacementObject = req.body.owner ? { owner: req.body.owner } : { hours: req.body.hours };

    try {
        await updateOwnerPromise(replacementObject, { new:true} );
        return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Owner updated successfully!' });
    } catch(err) {

        // TODO: handle error here
        console.log('Our error', err)
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to update owner, because of some issue at the server!' });
    }
}

// Modify the express route with the handler
router.put('/tasks/:id', updateOwnerPromiseAsync);
```